# Count Filtering and Arrayformulas in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I have a table of issued documents that I need to have numbered based on the name of the document and when it was issued, ie. the issuing of document 'a' on the 3/20/2039 was the 3rd document 'a'. Like this:

```
name date       order
a    3/20/2039  2
a    20/10/2099 3
a    10/12/2001 0
a    2/11/2019  1
b    2/12/2010  0
b    3/24/2017  1
b    3/20/2139  2
a    3/24/2111  4
a    3/24/3019  5
a    3/24/3034  6
```

I have a formula which is able to filter out and count the older dated versions of all documents under that same name:

```
=COUNTIF(FILTER(A:A,A:A=A2,B:B<B2),A2)
```

However, I can't create an arrayformula which works to do the same thing. I thought it could be:

```
=COUNTIF(FILTER(A:A,A:A=A2:A,B:B<B2:A),A2:A)
```

But this seems to be comparing and counting the entire range each time. Anybody know how to do this? I'm just getting to grips with Arrayformulas and this would be a fantastic help.

For anyone interested, an example table is shared here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15xnauVjACbWow1aTXVLMBawBuhZ0QcXdsh4HWHVYjyU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You could use query like this:

```
=query(A2:A,"Select A, count(A) where A is not null group by A label count(A) ''")
```

Comment: Kind of works, I basically need a countifs (multiple criteria) formula to count the documents which are: of the same name, and of an earlier date, related to each document if you see what I mean?